# Redis: get the values of a set as a stream

Tags: redis, lettuce

I just started learning Redis. For the client in the Java code I am evaluating lettuce. I wanted to get some values from a set as a stream, I copied the code from the unit test in Github and I was trying to use the class ListStreamingAdapter, but the import didn't work. I am using lettuce-core 5.0.5.RELEASE. The strange thing is that if I search the class in Github I can't find it, but if I search via Google I can find it and the history mentions it was moved, but I can't find it in the new package. At this point I'm wondering whether the unit tests are working, but for the moment my question is how can I get the values of a set as a stream without using this class?

....................................

Edit:
Note. I found a version of the ListStreamingAdapter in the test classes, but it is not what I was looking for. What I am trying to do is:

1) send a command that would select n members of a set and create a list.

2) retrieve the items of the list in small batches.

I can't paginate because the data is not sorted (but unique) and I can't retrieve the whole list at once because it's too big.